# PureComponent's shallowCompare is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of a child component (Review) by extending it from PureComponenet.

This component is being called from the parent component (Reviews), which is not a PureComponent.

By debugging I am seeing that whenever a change occurs to one of the review, all the reviews related to that product are getting re-rendered. Obviously Reviews' props gets updated and it passes individual Review's relevant props to individual Review components.
where I am also seeing this,

```
nextProps.reviewer === this.props.reviewer_info -> false
nextProps.reviewer_info = []
this.props.reviewer_info = []
```

I believe that pureComponent uses shallowCompare and it should return true while comparing 2 empty arrays, is that correct?

Does my parent component also needs to be a PureComponent in order to stop unnecessary rendering of my child components? Is that the missing part?

My review component has other child components, which I know also should be declared pureComponents. (I will update them but does this stop Review component from achieving pureComponent's benefits?)

Or above 2 are not the correct reasons for the re-rendering in-spite of using pureComponent and I am missing some other part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does my parent component also needs to be a PureComponent in order to stop unnecessary rendering of my child components?

No, that's not necessary.

> I believe that pureComponent uses shallowCompare and it should return true while comparing 2 empty arrays, is that correct?

It is not. The shallow comparison uses `===` to compare the old and new value of each property on `props` and `state`. But as you can see in a browser console `[] === []` is `false`. This is because each `[]` expression creates a new array object that is unequal to the others.

As a consequence, a simple array or object literal in a property (e.g. `<Review prop={[]}/>`) will trigger a rerender of `Review` whenever `Reviews` is rendered, negating the effect of the `PureComponent`.

To enjoy the optimized behavior, you will need to make sure that each non-primitive prop keeps referring to the same object instance as long as its value doesn't change (e.g. by keeping it in `Review`'s state). Furthermore, if there *is* a change, you will need to create a fresh top-level object for that prop, rather than modify the existing one in-place (so don't use `push` or assign directly to the prop objects properties.) The [immutable-js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) package can be helpful with this, but es6 spread operators often work fine as well.

> My review component has other child components, which I know also should be declared pureComponents. (I will update them but does this stop Review component from achieving pureComponent's benefits?)

It shouldn't affect `Review` (unless you create the children in the render method of `Reviews`, like `<Review ..>..<Child ../>..</Review>`, in which case `props.children` will change every time and trigger rerendering.)

Comment: One thing I know now is I am not suppose to use Pure Component for my usage.
"by keeping it in Review's state" you meant the global state (aka store) right? or the local state?

Comment: I was referring to `Review`'s local state, but any parent's state or the redux store will do, as long as you're not computing a new array each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate()` alternatively if your prop/state is an array:

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return JSON.stringify(this.props.reviewer_info) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.reviewer_info);
  }
```